# React HOC content component overflow screen

Tags: reactjs, layout, flexbox, higher-order-components

I am using HOC for my React project to create a template admin. But I don't know why the content of HomeScreen component, `<p>` tag is overflow to screen. Here is my code

HomeTemplate

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './home.module.css'
import HeaderBar from '../../component/HeaderBar/HeaderBar'
import SideBar from '../../component/Sidebar/SideBar'

export default function HomeTemplate(props) {

  const { Component, ...restProps } = props
  return <Route {...restProps} render={(propsRoute) => {
    return <div className={styles.home_container}>
      <div className={styles.home_container__headerBar}>
        <HeaderBar />
      </div>
      <div style={{display:'flex',flexDirection:'row',minHeight:'100vh'}}> 
        <div style={{minWidth:'30%'}}>
          <SideBar />
        </div>
        <div style={{}}>
          <Component {...propsRoute} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }} />
}
```

HomeScreen

```
[![import React from 'react'
import styles from './homescreen.module.css'
export default function HomeScreen(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box', background: 'green' }}>
      <p>asasasasasdsadsadsadsadasasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasasdasdasdasdasdasasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdassasdasdasdasdgdfgdf</p>
    </div >
  )
}
```

[image]

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeTemplate from './template/HomeTemplate/HomeTemplate';
import HomeScreen from './page/HomeScreen/HomeScreen'
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{maxWidth:'100%'}}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch >
          <HomeTemplate exact path="/homescreen" Component={HomeScreen} />
          <HomeTemplate exact path="/" Component={HomeScreen} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox and share for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem it was because the content in my p tag was a string without spaces,i add `wordBreak:'break-word'` and i tried a very long regular text and it worked fine